# How to print a specific column of characters using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to print the 55-60th character on each line of a file. I have to do this because I have a FORTRAN formatted file, and I don't have the same number of field separators on each line:

```
HETATM 3109  O   HOH B 999      10.307  26.441  12.306  0.26 30.00           O
HETATM 3110  O   HOH B1000      10.905  26.874  14.064  0.20 30.00           O
```

The characters `55-60` are the 10th field on the top line, and the 9th on the bottom line.
How can I print characters `55-60` using awk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-c` from `cut`:

```
$ cut -c55-60 file
  0.26
  0.20
```

From `man cut`:

> **-c**, --characters=LIST
>
> select only these characters

Or also `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/.{54}(.{6}).*/\1/' file
  0.26
  0.20
```

Or `awk` with [`substr()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html):

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,55,6)}' file
  0.26
  0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
rev file | awk '{print $3}' | rev
```

Comment: @User112638726 `rev` reverses the order of characters on each line.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate I know, but why ? This has nothing to do with printing a substring.

Comment: The question sounds like this `How to print a specific column of characters using awk`.

Comment: @User112638726 Yes, but in my example there are no irregularities in field separators for the last 3 columns. It's not the most general solution, but it works for the specific example.

Comment: You can use `awk '{print $(NF - 2)}'` instead of using `rev`.